# trouble with passing parameters within functions(setInterval)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code. https://www.jsfiddle.net/tpov743w/

I'm trying to accomplish multiple circular progress bars. The idea is to have them work dynamically, by adding additional progressCircle_# objects with different percentage values whenever needed. As you can see the progress bars load the data and executes the animation, but when I inspect the element in the browser I notice countless "ReferenceError: start is not defined". I need help in overcoming this problem. Thanks for any suggestions.

```js
var progressCircle_1 = {
  procent: 89,
  startFrom: 0,
  incrementBy: 1,
  canvasId: 'canvas',
  procentId: 'procent',
  funct: function() {
    var start = setInterval(function() {
      draw.call(progressCircle_1)
    }, 50);
  }
}
var progressCircle_2 = {
  procent: 59,
  startFrom: 0,
  incrementBy: 1,
  canvasId: 'canvas1',
  procentId: 'procent1',
  funct: function() {
    var start = setInterval(function() {
      draw.call(progressCircle_2)
    }, 50);

  }
}

progressCircle_1.funct();
progressCircle_2.funct();


function draw() {
  (this.startFrom < this.procent) ? this.startFrom++: clearInterval(start);
  var getCanvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasId).getContext('2d');
  var getNumber = document.getElementById(this.procentId).innerHTML = this.incrementBy++;
  getCanvas.beginPath();
  getCanvas.arc(250, 250, 100, 0, 0.06283185307179587 * this.startFrom);
  getCanvas.lineWidth = '15';
  getCanvas.strokeStyle = "white";
  getCanvas.lineCap = "round";
  getCanvas.stroke();
};
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#procent {
  font-size: 65px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 200px;
}

#procent::after {
  content: '%';
}

.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

#canvas1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#procent1 {
  font-size: 65px;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 660px;
  left: 200px;
}

#procent1::after {
  content: '%';
}

.container1 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

#canvasProgressBar {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="Interaktywny poradnik szybkiego startu dla Brackets.">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
</div>
<p id="procent"></p>
<div class="container1">
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500">
</div>
<p id="procent1"></p>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not try to bypass the request to post code when you post fiddles

Answer (score 1):

Just add `var start` at the top instead of inside the `funct` function

Complete JS Code:

```
var start

var progressCircle_1 = {
  procent:89,
  startFrom:0,
  incrementBy:1,
  canvasId:'canvas',
  procentId:'procent',
  funct: function(){
    start = setInterval(function(){draw.call(progressCircle_1)},50);
  }
}
var progressCircle_2 = {
  procent:59,
  startFrom:0,
  incrementBy:1,
  canvasId:'canvas1',
  procentId:'procent1',
  funct: function(){
    start = setInterval(function(){draw.call(progressCircle_2)},50);
  }
}

progressCircle_1.funct();
progressCircle_2.funct();


function draw(){
  (this.startFrom<this.procent)?this.startFrom++:clearInterval(start);
  var getCanvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasId).getContext('2d');
  var getNumber = document.getElementById(this.procentId).innerHTML=this.incrementBy++;
  getCanvas.beginPath();
  getCanvas.arc(250,250,100,0,0.06283185307179587*this.startFrom);
  getCanvas.lineWidth='15';
  getCanvas.strokeStyle="white";
  getCanvas.lineCap="round";
  getCanvas.stroke();
};
```

Comment: Tried that before. This partly solves the problem, but creates a new one. Namely, the progressCircle_1 runs forever, doen't stop at the declared 89 value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the interval id as well: https://jsfiddle.net/x8Lypm2j/

```js
var progressCircle_1 = {
  procent:89,
  startFrom:0,
  incrementBy:1,
  canvasId:'canvas',
  procentId:'procent',
  intervalId: 0,
  funct: function(){
    this.intervalId = setInterval(function(){draw.call(progressCircle_1)},50);
  }
}
var progressCircle_2 = {
  procent:59,
  startFrom:0,
  incrementBy:1,
  canvasId:'canvas1',
  procentId:'procent1',
  intervalId: 0,
  funct: function(){
    this.intervalId  = setInterval(function(){draw.call(progressCircle_2)},50);
  }
}

progressCircle_1.funct();
progressCircle_2.funct();


function draw(){
  (this.startFrom<this.procent)?this.startFrom++:clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  var getCanvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasId).getContext('2d');
  var getNumber = document.getElementById(this.procentId).innerHTML=this.incrementBy++;
  getCanvas.beginPath();
  getCanvas.arc(250,250,100,0,0.06283185307179587*this.startFrom);
  getCanvas.lineWidth='15';
  getCanvas.strokeStyle="white";
  getCanvas.lineCap="round";
  getCanvas.stroke();
};
```

Comment: That solved it. So simple that it should be so obvious. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass start to the calling function, you specify that the function's this is progressCircle_1 but it doesn't have a start attribute, so you need to pass the timeoutId(start) to the calling function.

```
    var progressCircle_1 = {
  procent:89,
  startFrom:0,
  incrementBy:1,
  canvasId:'canvas',
  procentId:'procent',
  funct: function(){
    var start = setInterval(function(){draw.call(progressCircle_1,start)},50);
  }
}
var progressCircle_2 = {
  procent:59,
  startFrom:0,
  incrementBy:1,
  canvasId:'canvas1',
  procentId:'procent1',
  funct: function(){
    var start = setInterval(function(){draw.call(progressCircle_2,start)},50);

  }
}
progressCircle_1.funct();
progressCircle_2.funct();


function draw(start){
  (this.startFrom<this.procent)?this.startFrom++:clearInterval(start);
  var getCanvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasId).getContext('2d');
  var getNumber = document.getElementById(this.procentId).innerHTML=this.incrementBy++;
  getCanvas.beginPath();
  getCanvas.arc(250,250,100,0,0.06283185307179587*this.startFrom);
  getCanvas.lineWidth='15';
  getCanvas.strokeStyle="white";
  getCanvas.lineCap="round";
  getCanvas.stroke();
};
```